# Посчитать количество слов в файле и в конце его вставить это значение

Tags: c++, файлы

Нужно вставить в конце файла количество слов

````
```
void word_count(const char* fname) {
    ifstream fin(fname);
    if (!fin.is_open()) {
        cerr << "Can't open";
        return;
    }

    string temp_name = "temp.txt";
    ofstream ftmp(temp_name);
    string s;
    int cnt = 0;

    while (getline(fin, s))
        ftmp << s << '\n';

    fin.seekg(0);

    while (fin >> s)
        cnt++;

    ftmp << cnt << '\n';

    fin.close(); ftmp.close();
    remove(fname);
    s = "rename " + temp_name + " " + fname;
    system(s.c_str());
}
```
````

Но почему-то перемещение курсора будто не работает и в конце файла всегда пишется '0'

Comment: В общем случае неизвестно, кратен ли размер файла слову.

Comment: @ТарасАтавин Что это значит?

Comment: так читайте слова, потом  установитесь в конец файла для записи и записывайте. Зачем лишние другие действия?

Answer (score 0):

```
ifstream fin(fname);    
std::string word;
size_t count{};
while (fin >> word) ++count;
fin.close();
ofstream fout(fname, std::ios_base::app);
fout << count;
fout.close();
```

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: А причём здесь слова?